# Google Drive API - PHP (CRUD)

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I tried to make script that editing google spreadsheets. But documentation it's not enough to understand how exactly work API. I made registration in API Manager and I downloaded the json file. Could you give me some examples how I can edit document in google drive? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Google Realtime API`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/overview), it provides collaboration as a service for files in Google Drive via the use of operational transforms. The API is a JavaScript library hosted by Google that provides collaborative objects, events, and methods for creating collaborative applications.

Realtime API data model may change as a result of edits that were made by someone other than the current user. Realtime data models are "eventually consistent." That means that if all collaborators stop editing, eventually everyone will see the same data model.

Applications where multiple people need to edit the same data simultaneously. Document editors are excellent examples of this kind of application. The Realtime API handles all aspects of data transmission, storage, and conflict resolution when multiple users are editing a file.

For scripting, use [`Class DocumentApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document), the document service creates and opens [Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document) that can be edited. Documents may be opened or created using DocumentApp.

```
// Open a document by ID.
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('DOCUMENT_ID_GOES_HERE');

// Create and open a document.
doc = DocumentApp.create('Document Name');
```

Here's a documentation how to update drive files: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update